# Xcode UIScrollView layout - set horizontal content size and resize subviews horizontally

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a scroll view that takes up the entire screen for a view. In this scroll view, there are several text fields stacked vertically. Due to there being too many of these text fields, I am using a scroll view, so the user can scroll down. I am using Xcode's Preview so I can set the view up to work on many devices. The problem I have is that I want these text fields to change horizontal size to fit, so there is no horizontal scrolling; however I can never get them to change size. Rather, the scroll view just lets me scroll horizontally.

I set this up in Xcode's interface builder (the scroll view and the text fields), and had Xcode apply all of its suggested constraints. Then, I put in a constraint for each of these text fields that set their right edges to be a set distance away from the scroll view (I could not set a distance from the actual view because the scroll view is the superview). These constraints did not clash with any existing constraints. There was no width set for any of these text fields by Xcode's suggested constraints.

Then in the `viewDidLoad:` method: `[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, scrollView.contentSize.height)];`

This in an attempt to force the scroll view to use the super view's horizontal width.

I am sorry about the vagueness of my question. **Essentially, I need a way for text fields in a scroll view to resize horizontally to fit the screen.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you apply the "edge" constraints for the text fields in relation to the scroll view.

You should add them in relation to their superview i.e. The scroll iew's content view.

When dealing with autolayout and scroll views, try to think of all the subviews as trying to define the content view's frame in an unambiguous way so the scrollview can "resize" properly.

Apple has set up a technical note for this kind of issues.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

Comment: How do you apply the constraint to the content view?

Comment: Are you using auto-layout in IB?

Comment: Yes. Right now, I changed it so I have a view within the scroll view which holds my items. I am getting closer, but still having trouble. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using AutoLayout and had trouble with a scrollview still scrolling horizontally that was slightly narrower than screen width.

This is my fix:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(MIN([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, self.scroller.frame.size.width), scroller.contentSize.height)];
}
```